# How to change id of inner HTML attributes in Typescript at the time of cloning

Tags: javascript, angularjs, typescript

I have accordion and I am cloning that by using Typescript, now I am stuck that how to change the ids of attributes of inner html divs.

```
public clone(): any {
    for (let i = 0; i < 2; i++) {
        this.linkTag = "#collapse" + this.cloneCount;
        this.collapseCount = "collapse" + this.cloneCount;
        var cloneObj = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById('clonedRow');
        //var cloneDone = angular.copy(cloneObj);   
        var cloneDone = cloneObj.cloneNode(true); 
        var hrefCount = this.linkTag;
        var clonedRowId = "clonedRow" + this.cloneCount;
        var cloneAccordionToggleID = "accordionToggleID" + this.cloneCount;
        //I want something like this in typescript
        //jQuery("#"+clonedRowId).find('.accordion-toggle').attr('href', this.linkTag).parents('.php').find('.panel-collapse').attr('id', this.collapseCount);

        document.getElementById('doClone').appendChild(cloneDone);
        this.cloneCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: Please share a Plunkr link that contains the related code

Comment: i already gave the related code in question

Comment: You should ask yourself if  you really need `id` attribute values when you clone elements. It will be easier if you just drop those and access elements later by their common class name -- which results in a node list -- and then take the nth element from that.

Comment: If you really are using angularjs (which isn't obvious from the code you supplied), this code goes against nearly every principle angularjs was designed around.  The entire purpose of using angularjs is to allow the framework to manage the interaction between your data and your DOM, so that you only have to modify the DOM ***when you have no other choice***.

Comment: @trincot yes i need to change the ids as i am cloning the accordion, in which ids should be different so that the href id and collapse/expand div id should match correspondingly